# Dismiss view controller that was presented from a different method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a custom UIViewController with one method and dismiss the same UIViewController from another method.

The method being used to present the controller:

```
-(void)presentViewController {
    self.customView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.customView setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:self.customView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The method being used to dismiss the controller:

```
-(void)dismissViewController {
    [self.customView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When creating a button within my `customView`, that calls `dismissViewController`, nothing happens. I know the method is being called because the `completion:` tag is working, yet nothing happens visually. No errors are being printed to console either.

Maybe I'm doing the whole thing wrong but any help is appreciated! Just trying to learn.

Comment: Show the code that call `dismissViewController` and explain clearly in which class the method are...

Comment: If you tell the app to refer to some view controller as 'self.customView = [[UIViewController alloc] init],' it certainly won't know which view controller you are referring to.

Comment: Please indicate which classes these methods belong to. Also, if you could add the code that handles the tap on the button, that might help.

Comment: Please try to follow the advices in the comments